# Trouble Using Google Maps with Bokeh Server, want to dynamically zoom

Tags: bokeh

I'd like to translate the Google Maps Bokeh app to a Bokeh Server App that allows zoom.  This is the bokek app I'm attempting to modify:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html

This is my attemp to translate to a bokeh server application:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
import random

text = TextInput(title="title", value='my sine wave')

zoom_slider = Slider(title='Zoom Level', value=11, start=0, end=20, step=1)
lat_textbox = TextInput(title='Latitude', value='30.2861')
lon_textbox = TextInput(title='Longitude', value='-97.7394')

source_gps = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lat=[30.29, 30.20, 30.29], lon=[-97.70, -97.74, -97.78]))
source_map = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(map_options=[GMapOptions(lat=30.2861, lng=-97.7394, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)]))

p = gmap("YOUR GOOGLE API CREDENTIALS HERE", 
source_map.data['map_options'][0], title="Austin")
p.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=15, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source_gps)


def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    zoom = zoom_slider.value
    lat = float(lat_textbox.value)
    lon = float(lon_textbox.value)
    source_map.data = dict(map_options=[GMapOptions(lat=lat, lng=lon, map_type="roadmap", zoom=zoom)])
    source_gps.data = dict(lat=[30.29 + random.random() / 10 - 0.05, 30.20, 30.29],
                           lon=[-97.70 + random.random() / 10 - 0.05, -97.74, -97.78])


for w in [zoom_slider, lat_textbox, lon_textbox]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)

# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = column(zoom_slider, lat_textbox, lon_textbox)

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, p, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Google Map"
```

I'd expect the google map to zoom according to the value of the zoom slider, but it's static.  Any ideas?

UPDATED!!  Thanks to bigreddot, this is the working code:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
import random

text = TextInput(title="title", value='my sine wave')

zoom_slider = Slider(title='Zoom Level', value=11, start=0, end=20, step=1)
lat_textbox = TextInput(title='Latitude', value='30.2861')
lon_textbox = TextInput(title='Longitude', value='-97.7394')

source_gps = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lat=[30.29, 30.20, 30.29], lon=[-97.70, -97.74, -97.78]))
initial_map_options = GMapOptions(lat=30.2861, lng=-97.7394, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)

p = gmap("YOUR GOOGLE API CREDENTIALS HERE", 
map_options=initial_map_options, title="Austin")
p.circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=15, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source_gps)


def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    zoom = zoom_slider.value
    lat = float(lat_textbox.value)
    lon = float(lon_textbox.value)
    source_gps.data = dict(lat=[30.29 + random.random() / 10 - 0.05, 30.20, 30.29],
                       lon=[-97.70 + random.random() / 10 - 0.05, -97.74, -97.78])
    p.map_options = GMapOptions(lat=lat, lng=lon, map_type="roadmap", zoom=zoom)


for w in [zoom_slider, lat_textbox, lon_textbox]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)

# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = column(zoom_slider, lat_textbox, lon_textbox)

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, p, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Google Map"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map options, i.e. the zoom level, are a property of the *plot*, not of the data source. If you want to update the map options you need to do something like:

```
p.map_options = new_map_options
```

somewhere in your update function.